# Math: Storing 11 values in 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, algebra, spline

I need to compare some melcpstrums (audio coefficients).

For example, the 11 mceps for one audio are

```
mcepsA[0]=4.93723823
mcepsA[1]=2.3972343
mcepsA[2]=1.2305712
```

etc.

Now I need to compare these with 11 different mceps, for example with

```
mcepsB[0]=3.9902323
mcepsB[1]=1.988323
mcepsB[2]=9.93723
```

etc.

I am calculating the audible difference like this:

```
double diff=0;

for (unsigned int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
   if (mcepsA[i] > mcepsB[i])
   {
        diff+=mcepsA[i]-mcepsB[i];
   }
   else
   {
        diff+=mcepsB[i]-mcepsA[i];
    }
}
```

However, storing all the mcep values is really problematic for me.
Unfortunately I am not a mathematician.
Is there somebody here who recognizes this problem and perhaps knows a solution for me where I can perhaps store all mcepsA in one value instead of having 11 of them?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why is it a problem: because it takes too much memory? FYI, mathematically what you're doing is known as [L1 distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L1_distance) in R^11 (but your loop only goes up to 10?).

Comment: Yes, storing (and more ->) retrieving (because of the massive amount of data) the values quickly from the disk is a problem for me. I improved my post to reflect that my for-next-statement goes up to 11).

Comment: The likeliest place to speed up is in reducing the number of calls to this comparison function; if you need nearest-neighbors, for example, use a kd-tree or similar rather than a full nearest-neighbors search. If you post what you're actually doing with these comparisons, we can maybe give advice there. For speeding up the actual distance fn: depending on what the data looks like, you may be able to do some form of dimensionality reduction. Perhaps an L1 version of [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_components_analysis), for example.

Comment: I am testing X sound files against Y sound files and using the mcep comparision I know which audio files I can join smoothly. As I said I am not a mathematician. Just throwing topics at me would not help (although I do know PCA... but in this case I have no idea how it would help me).

Comment: There's a well-known principle stating that you can't even stuff 2 values in one, it's known as the Pigeonhole Principle. That said, it sounds like a classical XY problem: you have problem X, think you have a solution to X, but that fails because problem Y. Ask the real question X.

Comment: I only have the answer, it is 42... For real, I am not sure what you mean. I want to reduce the amount of data that is required to find out the acoustic distance between audio X and audio Y.

Comment: @tmighty The idea with PCA is that you could maybe reduce the 11 components to, say, 3. Depending on your exact problem, you may or may not get almost-as-good performance with 3/11 of the data. But it seems like the real problem is not the 11 numbers; it's the collection of them, and you're asking about the part of the computation that can't really be sped up. If you post a more complete description of how you're using this 11-number comparison, that's where real savings are probably possible.

Comment: @Dougal The calculation itself is lightening fast, that is not the problem. My problem is getting the huge amounts of data from the disk as possible as possible. I have tried anything. The disk spins are the bottleneck. And since I can not resolve this (I can't tell the users to buy an SSD disk), the only solution to me seems to be a reduction of data. It takes quite a while to fseek from position A to position B to read the required data. Therefore I need to reduce the amounts of data.

Comment: About PCA: You don't have any code that I could use, do you? The only implementation of PCA I saw was in OpenCV, and I would need weeks to just adopt it to my needs.

Comment: @tmighty I'm not disagreeing with you here. What I'm saying is that you're unlikely to really speed up this part of the computation: at best you could get a factor of 2 or so from dimensionality reduction like PCA. What you need to do is reduce the number of times you do this computation / load the relevant data. In order to do so, we need to know how you're actually using it. Are you just comparing each of the 400k units in each file to the 400k in another one?

Comment: @Dougal Let's say I need to compare 480 units. This is a real life example. They are shattered all of the mceps file. The calculations themselves do not take more than 1 ms, this is perfectly fine. However, freading the mcep data from the disk takes really long. I tried memory-mapping the file, but it did not result in the gain of speed that I need. Therefore I am looking for a way to use less data to keep my mceps file smaller.

Comment: After reading all the comments, it seems like you want to reduce the amount of data you want to read from disk storage. But like @MSalters suggested the mcep data amounts to about 40MB. Why can't all of this be preloaded in memory prior to your calculations. Is your problem is speeding up 'preloading' part, since the `mcep` data is 'scattered' around in an audio file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 11 cepstrum values are deduced from hundreds, if not thousands of audio samples. You **really, really** need to check where your performance problems are originating; it's rather unlikely that these few lines are the problem.

That said, use `diff += abs(mcepsA[i]-mcepsB[i]);`.

Comment: My problem is getting the massive amounts of data from the disk. I think your formula does not equal to what I am doing above. You are not paying to attention to whether mcepsA[i] is bigger than mcepsB[i], aren't you?

Comment: Sorry, missed the essential bit.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. My problem is the massive amount of data. I would like to reduce it.

Comment: @tmighty: I really still am missing the problem then. Computers are quite good at processing massive amounts of data. The time needed for the code you showed is literally measured in nanoseconds. To me it sounds like you're running a debug executable or something similar.

Comment: The problem is that there are like 400.000 units in my file. Now when I want to compare unit 10393 against unit 399372, the disk takes quite a while to spin to where I stored the mceps in the file (and from where I fread it). The only solution that I see is to reduce the amount of mceps. That would make the disk access quicker. I have tried anything in aspects of disk access. Reducing the amount of data (and thus the disk spins) is the only solution that I see.

Comment: @tmighty: Right, like suspected: that is the real question. Could you turn that into a new question instead of a comment exchange? That way more people will see it.

Comment: But data can only be reduced by changing the way I calculate the acoustic difference. I guess you would go for something else, right? What would the right question be in your opinion?

Comment: You have 400.000 x 11 x 8 bytes. That's <40 MB. Disk does not matter.

Comment: Well, it is a problem if you have to jump around a lot in the file. But thanks anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39190/discussion-between-msalters-and-tmighty)